# Telerik RadGrid binding to large DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have successfully gotten a RadGrid to bind to a large DataTable that takes a lengthy query to produce. My problem is that the RadGrid will only show one page, and has to post back when the user changes page, and I lose my DataTable and must do this huge query once again.

I tried to Ajaxify the RadGrid, but it still calls Page_Load so I can't save my DataTable. (is it supposed to do that?)

What can I do differently? Thanks.

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager runat="server">
            <AjaxSettings>
                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="rgReport">
                    <UpdatedControls>
                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="rgReport" 
                            LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                    </UpdatedControls>
                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
            </AjaxSettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>

            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" IsSticky="False" Style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"  EnableSkinTransparency="true" Transparency="0">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>

 <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgReport" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50" 
                    AllowSorting="True" OnNeedDataSource="rgReport_NeedsDataSource" OnItemCommand="rgReport_ItemCommand"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowStatusBar="True" CellSpacing="0" 
                    GridLines="None">
                    <ClientSettings>
                        <ClientEvents OnRowMouseOver="CBGridRowMouseOver" OnRowMouseOut="CBGridRowMouseOut" /> 
                    </ClientSettings>
                    <MasterTableView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="submissionID"  Name="Master">
                        <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to Pdf"></CommandItemSettings>
                        <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" 
                            Visible="True">
                        </RowIndicatorColumn>
                        <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" 
                            Visible="True">
                        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="customerID" HeaderText="customerID" HeaderButtonType="None" 
                                DataField="customerID">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store that DataTable in the [cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on server side, and of course you if you do that you should manage that cache, eg. clear it if data is changed.

Now your code should look something like this :

```
string cacheID = "myCacheID"; 
DataTable data = null;
if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheID] == null)
{
  data = GetThatHugeDataTable();
  HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheID, data);
}
else
{
  data = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheID];
}
```

And when data changes clear the cache :

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(cacheID);
```

Be aware that this will consume a lot of memory on web server, of course depending on how big is that DataTable.